# Selecting a DOM element using javascript document.myElementsName

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a website which was coded a while ago.
I've found a Javascript function that uses the following syntax to set a value for a text box

```
document.myForm.myText.value = "value";
```

I've tested this code and it works in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

My question is whether this way of setting/selecting DOM elements is ok going forward (ie. is it going to get depreciated)? Should I change instances of this type of element selecting to the more standard (in my experience) code below?

```
document.getElementById("myText").value = "value";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it'll make a difference cause the browsers dom representation will have change to break the code; That'll probably break half the web pages on the internet.

Your code is better than the first because you will then be coding to the contract of the method `getElementById`, which returns the `HTMLElement` you need. This means that the JS Engine has to adhere to the standards of ECMAScript and return the exact element. Hence your code doesn't need to worry if tomorrow a browser changes it's structure and your element is now document.forms.myForm.myText.value instead of what you anticipated.